# Caffe Pruning Connections

Tags: c++, caffe

I want to implement connections pruning in Caffe like it was described in this [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5784-learning-both-weights-and-connections-for-efficient-neural-network.pdf). Basically all the weights that are close to zero should have no interference in the forward and backward propagation. The author says: "Caffe was modified to add a mask which disregards
pruned parameters during network operation for each weight tensor.". I added an extra blob to each layer containing the mask. Now I wanted to change conv_layer.cpp and inner_product_layer.cpp to load that extra blob and disregard the pruned parameters. However, I don't understand the code written in these layers and I can't find any documentation on it. Can anyone explain me the source code of these files?

Answer (score 0):

See [PerforatedCNN](https://github.com/mfigurnov/perforated-cnn-caffe) for using "masked" convolutions, it might help.
Edit: There is a PR for Caffe to support pruning of FC layers: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/4294